# Can I add other attributes to magento's flat product catalog table?

Tags: php, magento

I am in the process of optimizing magento store, and I've run across a couple of posts that recommend using the Flat Product Catalog for stores with a large amount of SKUs.

As I have over 10K products I thought I'd give it a try. However, when using the Flat Product Catalog only a select few attributes are loaded in product object (e.g. SKU, name, short description). And my template displays a few other attributes in the search/browse view, such as Manufacturer and Color.

Is there a way to add these attributes to the flat product catalog table so they too can be accessed?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1.4.x.x, just go into the attributes you want to be used in the **"Flat Product Catalog"** and make sure the property **"Used in Product Listing"** is set to **Yes**. Upon making changes, reindex **"Flat Product Data"**

The following properties cause the attribute to be included in the "Flat Product Catalog":

```
"Use in Layered Navigation" = Yes
"Used in Product Listing" = Yes
"Used for Sorting in Product Listing" = Yes
```

Comment: "Used in Product Listing" seems to be the key.  I had several attributes that were already "Use in Layered Navigation" but they weren't showing up in the catalog_product_flat_1 table until I set "Used in Product Listing" too.

Answer (score 11):

I have been working through this issue too, which I would describe as "cannot access product collection attribute in flat mode" or "addAttributeToSelect not working in flat mode".

I found a "clean" solution which:

- does not require the attribute to have specific settings in admin (it might be added by a user, or hidden on the front end)
- works for both flat and non-flat mode

Please note - in the code below I have used the associated product collection, but this applies to any product collection (specifically, anything inheriting from `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`)

Failing code:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute( 'sku', 'ABC123' );
$coll = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect( 'my_custom_attribute' )
;
```

In flat mode, the above code silently fails to add the attribute if it happens not to be in the flat table.

Working code:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute( 'sku', 'ABC123' );
$coll = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getAssociatedProductCollection()
    ->joinAttribute( 'my_custom_attribute', 'catalog_product/my_custom_attribute', 'entity_id', null, 'left' )
    ->addAttributeToSelect( 'my_custom_attribute' )
;
```

The `joinAttribute` method adds a join to the query.  It works even if this duplicates an attribute that's already in the flat table.

Note that I've used a `left` join there, to ensure that it fetches products if `my_custom_attribute` is not set on those products.  You can change that for `inner` if you're only interested in rows where `my_custom_attribute` is set.

**(tested in CE 1.6.2.0)**

Comment: The only logical solution to the problem! Thank you

Comment: nice. This is still relevant for magento 2!

Answer (score 5):

Others have provided the usually sufficient answer (setting Used In Product Listing to Yes), but I found an edge case that would have been useful to know when I was searching for this same thing.

If you are using a custom source model for the custom attribute you would like to include in the flat product table, you will have to override `getFlatColums()` in the source model class. Yes, I know it's misspelled, but that's native Magento for you.

**Sample**:

```
public function getFlatColums() {
    return array($this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode() => array(
        'type'      => 'tinyint',
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'is_null'   => true,
        'default'   => null,
        'extra'     => null
    ));
}
```

**Source**: http://www.dconstructing.com/2012/03/14/custom-product-attributes-and-flat-database-tables-in-magento

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make use of an attribute in a module while using the flat product table (filter a collection of products for example) you could add it to a module's Module_File.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <product>
            <collection>
                <attributes>
                    <your_custom_attribute /> <!-- This is the attribute name -->
                </attributes>
            </collection>
        </product>
    </frontend>
</config>
```