# Magento - add media gallery attribute to product flat table

Tags: php, magento

How do I add a 'media_gallery" attribute type to products flat table, so that it can be used in product listing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be added by defining "Used in Product Listing" to Yes
Once you have done this, you will need to re-index the Product Flat

EDIT:  See solution for the final answer.

Source: [Can I add other attributes to magento's flat product catalog table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271284/can-i-add-other-attributes-to-magentos-flat-product-catalog-table)

Solution:
[Media Images not available in Magento’s product list?](http://thedistance.co.uk/journal/2011-10/missing-magento-media-images)
[Media Images not available in Magento’s product list? - archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140218073118/http://thedistance.co.uk/journal/2011-10/missing-magento-media-images)

Comment: Media gallery attribute can't be defined as "Used in Product Listing" - Yes, except with a manual sql field modification

Comment: Yes it can, what version of Magento are you on? I just did it in my dev copy at version 1.7 RC1.  I just found it on my flat table with all NULL fields.

Comment: 1.6.2 - so in 1.7rc1 you can specify "used in product listing" even for media attribute type? can't do that in 1.6.x admin, it's cool if 1.7 can do that

Comment: I created a 1.6.2 copy as well, and it let me specify the option, I am re-indexing the table now, but it's 300k products so it takes some time.

Comment: The field is index in my 1.6.2 copy as well.

Comment: You typed your attribute type incorrectly, you said media_gallery which is a valid attribute in the Manage Attributes.  Look at this. http://thedistance.co.uk/journal/2011-10/missing-magento-media-images

Comment: I appologize for the mistake, as for the solution - it is ingenious indeed :) Simple but effective hack

Answer (score 0):

To change it programmatically, you could do.

```
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_product', '{field_code_here}', 'used_in_product_listing', 1);
```

Then reindex.