# Magento Export - Gallery field is always blank

Tags: magento, export, gallery, image-gallery

I'm trying to export the image gallery field called "gallery", which ideally should have a comma separated list of images in the gallery.  This field is standard field in magento.

The field is always blank when I export out of the Magento admin site.  It works great on one of my sites, but 2 others are completely blank.

The only difference between the site that works and the other sites is that there are two stores on the site that works.

I checked the database and noticed there were some missing records in "catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value" so I added these based on the records in catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.  After doing that, still nothing is exports in this field.

Is there anything special that is needed to get this field to export?

Comment: I have "Use Flat Category" disabled, but it appears that there is a NULL value in the "gallery" field.  I tried dropping the column, but it was re-created with NULL values again.  It should be noted on the site that works, there is no gallery field in product_flat_index. Also found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974513/magento-add-media-gallery-attribute-to-product-flat-table which seems to be solution, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  It turns out that the custom export module wasn't enabled.

(4 hours of my life i won't get back.)