# Loading magento product sku and assigned drop down attribute value via product collection

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom attribute for product called `warehouse` of type drop down.

In order to load the `Sku => Warehouse` (get assigned value for each product) updates between dates via models; I do the following:

```
// Load warehouse attribute options
$warehouse_options = array();
$options = array();
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'warehouse');
if ($attribute->usesSource()) {
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false);
}
$attribute = null;
foreach ($options as $option) {
    $warehouse_options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
}
$options = null;

// Load all products updated since last sync
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array(
    'from' => $datetime_from,
    'to' => $datetime_to,
    'date' => true
));

// Init results
$results = array(
    'ServerDateTime' => $datetime_now,
    'Mapping' => array()
);

// Build results
foreach ($collection as $p) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p->getId());
    $results['Mapping'][] = array(
        'Sku' => $product->getSku(),
        'Warehouse' => isset($warehouse_options[$product->getWarehouse()]) ? $warehouse_options[$product->getWarehouse()] : ''
    );
    $product = null;
}
$collection = null;
```

This works, but quite slow as each product is getting loaded, so if I had `3000` products, thats `3000+` queries.

Is there a way to optimise this so I can load the desired data with minimal amount of query & processing?

---

I have tried to use just the collection like this using `addAttributeToSelect`:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku', 'warehouse');
```

However, the returned `$collection->getData()` does not contain the field `warehouse`. Here's an example response array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => 1
            [entity_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [updated_at] => 2015-07-07 15:35:35
            [sku] => C13S041061
        )
```

Comment: Used `addFieldToSelect` instead of `addAttributeToSelect`.

Comment: No, `addAttributeToSelect` is correct, as he's using an EAV attribute

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku', 'warehouse');`, you should be passing an array of all the details you want, not as separate function paramaters.

(Take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addAttributeToSelect($attribute, $joinType = false)`

So, your call should be:

`$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'warehouse'));`

In fact, you should be able to call:

`$collection->addAttributeToSelect('warehouse');`

as `SKU` should be a default value you get whether you specify it or not.

This will allow you to lose the additional Model call within your loop (which will really be killing your speed). With regard to the best way to go from here,  my personal favourite is paged collections.  Take a look here: http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/dealing-with-large-collections-in-magento/

Essentially, something like this (example orders collection):

```
$ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$ordersCollection->setPageSize(100);

$pages = $ordersCollection->getLastPageNumber();
$currentPage = 1;

do {
    $ordersCollection->setCurPage($currentPage);
    $ordersCollection->load();

    foreach ($ordersCollection as $_order) {
        // process
    }

    $currentPage++;
    // clear collection (if not done, the same page will be loaded each loop) - will also free memory
    $ordersCollection->clear();
} while ($currentPage < = $pages);
```

Comment: I have tried `$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'warehouse'));` it's still not returning the `warehouse`.

Comment: Are you sure `warehouse` is the correct attribute name?

Comment: If you use: `$collection->addAttributeToSelect("*")` - you get warehouse?

Comment: Are you using `flat catalog`?  Is the property "Used in Product Listing" is set to Yes against the warehouse attribute?

Comment: Actually, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6271284/can-i-add-other-attributes-to-magentos-flat-product-catalog-table might be a good place to look if `flat catalog` is enabled.